# In RxJavaFx, how to get the Observable for Scene accelerator events?

Tags: java, rx-java2, rx-javafx

Looking at this:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaFX/issues/66

I can get the button click Observable via:

```
JavaFxObservable.actionEventsOf(loadUsersButton).subscribe(loadButtonSubject);
```

Is there a way to get an Observable for key presses that are the result of Scene accelerator events? I.e. an Observable that would emit events similar to:

```
scene.getAccelerators().put(keyCombination, runnableTriggeredOnEvents)
```

Comment: What's the use case for adding the accelerators manually?

Comment: @Slaw Setting global hotkeys. Is there a better way for that?

Comment: Not sure. I suppose one option/workaround is to just have the `Runnable` call `Button.fire()`, causing the `Button` to emit an `ActionEvent`.